# How can I optimize this query to get faster result?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

How can I optimize this query to get result from it faster?

```
update TblPartes 
inner join ( select TP.codigo1, 
                    COUNT(TE.id_codigo) AS COUNT
             FROM TblPartes TP 
             left JOIN TblExistencias as TE ON TP.id=TE.id_codigo 
             where TE.vendido = 0 
             or TE.vendido is null 
             or TE.vendido = 0 
             and TP.id_ubicacion is null 
             or TE.vendido is null 
             and TP.id_ubicacion is null 
             GROUP BY TP.id 
            ) as E on TblPartes.codigo1=E.codigo1 
set stock = E.count  
where TblPartes.codigo1=E.codigo1
```

Comment: Whenever you ask about SQL query optimization, **show the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: The first question is: Is it the UPDATE part that is slow, or the SELECT? Also, add `AND stock <> E.count` to the WHERE clause so you don't update rows that already have stock=E.count.

Comment: Thanks For Response, The Slow part is the select, not the Update.
TblPartes Has 13,000 Records and TblExistencias has 27.000 Records

On TblExistencias i have id as Primary Key1, and id_codigo as primary key2
On TblParts i have id and codigo1 as primary key, and i have used before codigo1 as primary key2.

Comment: So just look at the SELECT, and update your question per my instructions in the first comment.

Comment: It's also confusing and error-prone that you have many AND and OR conditions in the WHERE clause with no grouping parentheses.

Comment: The main idea of this query is because i have TblPartes (Products), With TblPartes.stock, These products are identified by codigo1, i have TblExistencias with same codigo1 field, and i must count and group by codigo and update the result (Stock) on TblPartes.stock

Comment: any help to get a better performance?

Comment: I already said what you needed to do to help us figure out what we could speed up. Please go back and read my original comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue boils down to the speed of this, correct?

```
    SELECT  TP.codigo1, COUNT(TE.id_codigo) AS COUNT
            FROM  TblPartes TP
            left JOIN  TblExistencias as TE  ON TP.id=TE.id_codigo
            where  TE.vendido = 0
              or  TE.vendido is null
              or  TE.vendido = 0
              and  TP.id_ubicacion is null
              or  TE.vendido is null
              and  TP.id_ubicacion is null
            GROUP BY  TP.id
```

Suggestions:

- Decide whether to use `0` versus `NULL`.  That way the query won't have to test for both.  (This may require changes to the data and how the data is loaded.)
- Note that `COUNT(x)` avoids counting when `x` is `NULL`; is that what you intended?
- You can probably avoid the `GROUP BY` (which may be a big factor in speed) by turning the `LEFT JOIN` into `EXISTS(SELECT ...)`.
- The `UPDATE` is testing for `TblPartes.codigo1=E.codigo1` twice`.
- Add parentheses were appropriate in that long boolean expression -- `and` and `or` may not be combining the way you expect!

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

These indexes *may* help:

```
TP:  INDEX(id_ubicacion, id,  codigo1)
TE:  INDEX(vendido, id_codigo)
```

Comment: Really thanks Rick, Query before upgrades takes 33 secs, now less than 1 second. Problem was on where and null values, i have update all rows to 0 and prevent null values and problem solved.

Comment: @Martin - Caution:  `LEFT JOIN t WHERE t.id IS NULL` is not testing for t.id being NULL, it is testing for the row being missing.  That is, did you get the right answer with your elimination of Nulls?